# Is it possible to connect to docker db container by name in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, docker, sqlalchemy

I have the following docker containers, which both share a network connection, and `exec`'ing into `api`, allows me to ping `db`, that bit is fine.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
8790d379ddb9        codeinsight/database   "/run-database.sh"       3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp             db
88b2022876cc        codeinsight/rest-api   "python /usr/src/a..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->8989/tcp   api
```

However, when connecting to `db` with sqlalchemy (probably not specific to the framework!) with:

```
self.engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user_name:password@db:3306/dbname', echo=True)
```

I get nothing but connection refused

`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused`

So, is it possible to connect by container name when a link is defined and established? Or am I doing it incorrectly? Am completely new to docker, and will happily hear best practices etc. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I disagree with the close vote, as this is specifically asking about a programming framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to connect by container name. I think, you need to properly configure `mysql` container to allow connections from `api` host with your `user_name` credentials.

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely connect the two containers, the key is using `links` directive.

so it'd be the following syntax:

```
docker run --links mongo:mongo <rest of your stuff> <image name for python app>
```

then on the app you would simply connected with host `mongo`

Comment: Upon closer inspection this is a legacy instruction which has been surpassed by allocating networks, which is the method I have used

Comment: Yes, and have confirmed that both containers are listed in inspect

Comment: I'm starting to think that mysql isn't listening on 0.0.0.0 and thus causing connect refusal, but I'm yet to figure out why my .cnf isn't being honored.